# Limiting instruments to specific variables in R (AER/ivreg)

Tags: instrumental-variables

I am analyzing a fixed-effects model with **seven endogenous and five instrumental variables**. In my model, instrumental variables are lagged, and I do not have any exogenous variables. As far as I understand, *AER* (also with *IVREG* package, derived from *AER*) applies the instruments to all endogenous variables in the model. Still, I want only two variables with instruments.

I was able to make it in Stata, but I want to know if it is also possible in  R.

> PS: I applied lags using dplyr to the dataset because using lag with *plm* or *dplyr* in the analysis did not work.

Comment: Why would you not want instruments for all your endogenous variables?

Comment: Following is from [the paper](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1540-6261.2004.00679.x ) that I obtained my base model:

>In estimating equation (9), we explicitly recognize the endogeneity of financial and investment decisions and use an instrumental variables (IV) approach.

Variables related to the decisions are only four, not all.

Comment: Yes, they instrument all endogenous variables, as usual, or so I read the quote. The exogenous regressors server as their own instruments, also as usual. That is also how ivreg operates. Not instrumenting for an endogenous regressor would lead to inconsistent estimators, so I doubt any package incorporates that!

Comment: Stata xtivreg package allows defining instrumented variables.

Comment: Yes, of course, but (I am not familiar with Stata) I suppose that not instrumenting a variable means assuming it to be exogenous (and hence, see above, serving as its own instrument).

Comment: I contacted Dr. Achim, this is what he responded:

ivreg(y ~ ex | en1 + en2 + en3 + en4 | in1 + in2 + in3 + in4 + in5, ...)